# Is There Any Security Risk to Opening an Official JavaScript File in Command Prompt?

Tags: javascript

I was studying how to create a simple app with [Vue.js Javascript framework](https://vuejs.org/) and downloaded the official and latest (as of today) CDN file from https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.36/dist/vue.global.js.
I saved the file locally to my computer, but accidentally double-clicked on the .js file, and it opened for a split second in the Windows command prompt on my Windows 10 computer. I'm wondering if there was any security risk when I accidentally opened it in the command prompt? This version of Vue was released about 2 weeks ago, so I don't think there are any Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE's) associated with it, but I thought I would check here anyways.

Comment: I guess you are safe, but suffer from this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237841/bound-cmd-as-default-program-for-js-files

Comment: I think the default Javascript host on Windows isn't good enough to run Vue.js :) So I think the Command prompt just show some syntax errors (which Windows Script Host cannot understand) then it kill itself.